# Can an application on two separate devices share a packet to similar resource?

Tags: routing, network, packet-analysis

Can packets requested for an image by an app on a phone be sent to same app on another phone by another user?

Comment: Look up the term `multicast`. Packets sent to a multicast group will be received by all the hosts with an application that has subscribed to the multicast group. Multicast does not work across the public Internet, and it is confined to a single LAN unless you have multicast routing (very different than the normal unicast routing) enabled on every router between the source and destination (no possible on the public Internet), but it is generally easy to use on a single LAN.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. Any packet (or rather data segment) is addressed to a specific socket that belongs to a certain application. Unless applications do anything between themselves (which would be off-topic here), the data only goes to one of them. And certainly, data isn't shared across devices.

Comment: Lets say an image on twitter was requested for by the twitter app. Can i pass the response (if i capture it) and send to another twitter app on another device waiting for same image

Comment: No, you cannot inject data into an application stream. (Only with a man-in-the-middle attack, or a caching proxy, but all off-topic here).